# How to set custom Attributes in keycloak JWT?

Tags: jwt, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I am making a storage provider that federated user from my local database my question I need to set the attributes of my custom user in the returning **JWT**.

I need  to carry the user from `customStorageProvider` to `JWTMapper` to map the attributes to **JWT**

Answer (score 3):

> I am making a storage provider that federated user from my local
> database my question I need to set the attributes of my custom user in
> the returning JWT.
>
> I need to carry the user from customStorageProvider to JWTMapper to
> map the attributes to JWT

That can be achieved with *protocol mappers*; they can map user-related attributes into the token. To create them via Admin Console, go to your realm:

- then to clients, and select the client that you will be authenticating against

Afterwards:

**(For the OLD Keycloak UI)**

- go to `Mappers`
- click on:

  - either `Create` (right side) to create your mapper
  - or `Add Builtin` to add a Keycloak's built-in mapper

**(For the NEW Keycloak UI)**

- go to the tab `Client Scopes`
- click on the client scope `<the client ID of your client>-dedicated` (*e.g.,* test-dedicated in the picture below)

[image]

- if you have never created a mapper for this client before, click on:

  - either `Configure a new mapper` to create your mapper
  - or click on `Add predefined mapper` to add a Keycloak's built-in mapper
- if you have already created mappers for this client before, click on `Add mapper` and select:

  - either `From predefined mappers` to create your mapper
  - `By configuration` to add a Keycloak's built-in mapper

Those mappers can also be automatically created with the [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html). To understand how check [this SO answer on "how o create mapper for each user attribute in Keycloak via REST API"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66915727/1366871).