# How to create mapper for each user attribute in Keycloak via REST API?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

How do I create Protocol Mappers with the following values (as seen in the attached image) via Keycloak's REST API? I couldn't find it in the documentation - I did find this: [Protocol Mapper](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_protocol_mappers_resource) - but the [ProtocolMapperRepresentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_protocolmapperrepresentation) takes in a Map and a couple of Strings. When I see the UI - I see a lot more fields and I'm not sure if I'm looking at the right API.

Here's the UI:

[image]

How do I do it via API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from the endpoint calls presented on this answer.

---

> How do I create Protocol Mappers with the following values (as seen in
> the attached image) via Keycloak's REST API?

You can do it by calling the following endpoint:

```
POST ${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/admin/realms/${REALM_NAME}/clients/${ID of the Client}/protocol-mappers/models
```

with the following data:

```
{"protocol":"openid-connect","config":{"id.token.claim":"true","access.token.claim":"true","userinfo.token.claim":"true","multivalued":"","aggregate.attrs":"","user.attribute":"some-attribute","claim.name":"some-attribute","jsonType.label":"String"},"name":"some-attribute","protocolMapper":"oidc-usermodel-attribute-mapper"}
```

> I did find this: Protocol Mapper - but the
> ProtocolMapperRepresentation takes in a Map and a couple of Strings.
> When I see the UI - I see a lot more fields and I'm not sure if I'm
> looking at the right API.

That is by design; to make the endpoint abstract enough to accept different types of Protocol Mappers. That Map encodes basically the config part which tend to change from mapper to mapper.

---

**Step-by-Step**

You can get that information using the [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html); to call that API, you need an access token from a user with the proper permissions. For now, I will be using the `admin` user from the `master` realm, but later I will explain how you can use another user:

```bash
curl “https://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token” \
    -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
    -d "username=${ADMIN_NAME}” \
    -d "password=${ADMIN_PASSWORD}" \
    -d "grant_type=password"
```

You get a JSON response with the admin's token. Extract the value of property `access_token` from that response. Let us save it in the variable `$ACCESS_TOKEN` for later reference.

To create the protocol mapper for your realm `$REALM_NAME`:

```bash
curl -X POST “https://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/admin/realms/${REALM_NAME}/clients/${ID_OF_CLIENT}/protocol-mappers/models” \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}” \
     -d "${PROTOCOL_JSON_DATA}"
```

An example of `"${PROTOCOL_JSON_DATA}"`:

```
'{"protocol":"openid-connect","protocolMapper":"oidc-hardcoded-claim-mapper","name":"test","config":{"claim.name":"test","claim.value":"test","jsonType.label":"","id.token.claim":"true","access.token.claim":"true","access.tokenResponse.claim":"false","userinfo.token.claim":"true"}}'
```

For those that need, I have scripts ([this one](https://github.com/dreamcrash/StackOverflow-/blob/main/Keycloak/RestAdminAPI/ProtocolMappers/createProtocolMapper.sh) or [this one](https://github.com/dreamcrash/Keycloak/blob/main/scripts/createClientProtocolMapper)) for the aforementioned steps.

**Assigning the proper user permissions**

For those that do not want to get an access token from the master admin user, you can get it from another user but that user needs the permission `manage-clients` from the `realm-management` client. For that you can:

**(OLD Keycloak UI)**

- Go to Users, and then the user in question
- Go to the tab `Role Mappings`
- In `client roles` select `realm-management`
- Select the role `manage-clients` and click on `Add selected`

**(New Keycloak UI)**

- Go to Users, and then the user in question
- Go to the tab `Role Mappings`
- Click on `Assign role`
- In `Search by role name` type `manage-clients`
- Select the role and assign it