# How to get custom attributes for a user in Keycloak using the RESTful API?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I would assume this to be straight forward but I can't find it in the docs.

The following curl command:

```
curl \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    'https://$URL/auth/realms/$REALM/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo'
```

results in:

```
{
  "sub": "8182...415",
  "email_verified": true,
  "name": "n.a. n.a.",
  "groups": [],
  "preferred_username": "foo@example.com",
  "given_name": "n.a.",
  "family_name": "n.a.",
  "email": "foo@example.com"
}
```

How do I get the custom attributes for a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the user attributes with the [get users](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.1/rest-api/index.html#_getusers) endpoint from Admin Rest API:

```
GET /{realm}/users
```

with the query parameters, `exact=true` and `username`.

**Step-by-Step:**

You can get that information using the [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html#_authentication_management_resourcer); to call that API, you need an access token from a user with the proper permissions. For now, I will be using the `admin` user from the `master` realm:

```bash
curl https://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token \
    -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
    -d "username=$ADMIN_NAME" \
    -d "password=$ADMIN_PASSWORD" \
    -d "grant_type=password"
```

You will get a JSON response with the admin's token. Extract the value of property `access_token` from that response. Let us save it in the variable `$ACCESS_TOKEN` for later reference.

To get the user attributes from your realm `$REALM_NAME`:

```bash
curl -X GET https://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/admin/realms/${REALM_NAME}/users/?username=${USERNAME}&exact=true \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

From the response extract the user `attributes` for example as follows:

```
jq -r .[].attributes
```

---

To retrieve custom user attributes via the `userinfo` endpoint you need to create a protocol Mapper for the client used to authenticate the user.

That mapper can also be created with the Keycloak Admin rest API. For a more detailed answer on how to create Protocol Mappers for user-attributes (including for the old and new Keycloak APIs) please have a look at the [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66915727/1366871).

Or you can do it via Keycloak Admin UI as follows, in the Keycloak go to:

- Select your `realm`
- Go to `clients`
- Select the appropriate `client` for your use-case

**(For the OLD Keycloak UI)**

- Go to `Mappers`
- Click `Create`
- Select `Mapper Type` as `User Attribute`
- Fill up the field `User Attribute` with your custom user attribute
- Set to be added to the `userinfo` endpoint
- Fill up the remaining fields, accordingly
- Click on `Save`

**(For the NEW Keycloak UI)**

- Go to the tab `Client Scopes`
- Click on the scope -dedicated (*e.g.,* test-dedicated in my example)

[image]

- Click on `Configure a new mapper` (or `Add Mapper` >  `By configuration` if you have already created mappers before for this client)

[image]

- Select `User Attribute`
- Fill up the field `User Attribute` with your custom user attribute
- Set to be added to the `userinfo` endpoint
- Fill up the remaining fields, accordingly
- Click on `Save`

This is enough to enabled `your custom user attribute` to be retrieved from the `userinfo` endpoint